# TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, express, angular5

I am using Angular 5 on front-end, Node on back-end and Mongo as the database. Now I am trying to save an image to the database but constantly getting this error. I can't figure out if I'm making mistake on front or back because this is my first time working with files. I did my research but it points mostly to angular 1.x.

**HTML Component**

```
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitPhoto()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="file" class="form-control" formControlName="photo">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Sačuvaj</button>
  </form>
```

**TS Component**

```
onSubmitPhoto() {
this.profile.photo = this.form.value.photo;
this.usersService.updatePhoto(this.profile, this.id)
  .subscribe(
  data => {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
  },
    error => console.error(error)
  );
}
```

**Service**

```
updatePhoto(profile: Profile, id: string) {
    const body = new FormData();
    body.append('photo', profile.photo);
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/profile/photo/' + id, body, { headers: headers })
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch((error: Response) => {
            return Observable.throw(error.json());
        });
}
```

**Node.JS**

```
   router.post('/photo/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files);
    User.find({ _id: req.params.id })
    .exec((err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occured',
                error: err
            });
        }
        user.img.data = fs.readFileSync(req.files);
        user.img.contentType = 'image/png';
        user.save((err, obj) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err
            }
            console.log('success')
        })
    });
});
```

**Model**

```
const schema = new Schema({
  img: { data: Buffer, contentType: String}
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

Any help is appreciated.
Also, loging req.files returns undefined.

Comment: You cant serialize a File object

Answer (score 1):

To upload a file you need to wrapp it in a `FormData` instance as follows:

```
interface Profile {
   photo: File;
}

updatePhoto(profile: Profile, id: string) {
    const body = new FormData();
    body.append('photo',profile.photo);
    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/profile/photo/${id}`, body,)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch((error: Response) => {
            return Observable.throw(error.json());
        });
}
```

Furthermore, your backend is most likely failing in the following section:

```
user.img.data = fs.readFileSync(req.body.photo);
```

Considering that you are now uploading a form with `multipart/form-data` encoding, you will need to use some middleware to parse the request in your backend as stated in the [expressjs doc](http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#req.body)

You could use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) or [express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload)

If you go with the second, you will need the following:

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

router.use(fileUpload());// use express-fileupload as default parser for multipart/form-data encoding

router.post('/photo/:id', (req, res) => {
User.find({ _id: req.params.id })
    .exec((err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occured',
                error: err
            });
        }
        user.img.data = req.files.photo.data;
        user.img.contentType = 'image/png';
        user.save((err, obj) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err
            }
            console.log('success')
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that you can access the uploaded file through the body property of the req object? Updated my answer

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I was already using 'express-fileupload'. Also it still throw error: Cannot read property 'photo' of undefined

Comment: Update your question with that information and your node.js version please

Comment: I've been working on something else I will update now, I managed to send photo to backend but having trouble with another error